# Regular expression in spring security context for query

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-security

I try to match this url in my spring security context xml:

> /settings/folder_0+folder_1+folder_2.yaml?tag=test

I tried :

> ```
>     <s:intercept-url pattern="/settings/(.*)([+]?)*.yaml?tag=test" access="hasAnyRole("ROLE")"/>
> ```

But it doesn't works. I can't figure out where I made a mistake.

Can someone help me ?

If it's possible I want to improve this regex in order to accept different format like yaml, json, ... and in order to accept any tag name.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with the regular expression in your Spring Security context XML.

Second, the question mark (?) in the pattern also has a special meaning in regular expressions and should be escaped as well.

Here's a revised regex that should match the URL you provided:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/settings/.*\\.(yaml|json)\\?tag=.*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE')" />
```